# MSBuild folder not included after installing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I installed Visual Studio 2015 program using a default installation.
Later, I installed WDK 10 and SDK 10.0.14393.795 separately.

I have to place two configuration files in the attached path shown below but I cannot find it:
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0

How can I fix that problem?
The system is Windows 7 64-bits

Best regards,
R. Ferreiro

Comment: Hi R.Ferreiro, you can go to Control Panel--Programs and Features, right click the VS 2015, Change-Modify, then check the custom component: Programming Languages--Visual C++--Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015 to install it. VS 2015 default installation includes C#/VB, Web and Desktop features. After the installation, check the above folder again.

Comment: Thank you Sara, I checked that feature and it was already installed. Do you have any possible ideas? Best regards, R. Ferreiro

Comment: Have you tried to repair VS 2015?

Comment: I have tried to repair it and neither does the folder appear.

Comment: Can you find this folder C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\? I can found this folder on my computer that already installed VS 2015, since your OS is Win7, make sure win7 SP1 already installed and windows update is up-to-date, modify VS 2015 and uncheck the option “Visual C++“ and its sub options to uninstall. After that, modify VS 2015 and check those components to re-install. If this issue persists, use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs and you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/  share the link here.

Comment: I only found the folder C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\, without 'MSBuild'. I checked that the SO wasn't up-to-date and I updated it. Later, I modified Visual Studio and re-installed Visual C++, but MSBuild folder doesn't appear yet. I attach vslogs.zip https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmzWRbrTidcjgmDp7cL8FTOMXJ0x

Comment: Finally, the required folder exists!. Once you open the program for the first time in order to choose the configuration, the folder is automatically created.                                                                                                Thank you very much for your help. The problem is SOLVED.                                              Best regards, R. Ferreiro

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that your issue is solved, could you please add a reply with your workaround when you have free time? It will help other community members who meet the same issue to easier search this information, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after performing several tests I solved the problem.
Firtsly, I updated my operating system with the latest updates.
Then, I installed Visual Studio 15, SDK and WDK 10 separately.

**Solution**: When Visual Studio is installed, open it the first time and the required MSBuild folder will be created.

Thank you for your help,
R. Ferreiro

Comment: Hi Ferreiro, you can mark your reply as answer when you have free time, it will help other community members who meet the same issue :)